# Interpolate NaN values in pyplot without using scipy.interpolate.griddata

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I want to know how can I interpolate the `plt.contourf` plot without interpolating the data itself. The problem is because when I tried `scipy.interpolate.griddata` It cost a lot of time because my data is too long.

I want to know if there is a way to do it by pyplot or something faster to plot a data with `NaNs` without these blanks.

For example:

If I have:

```
import numpy as np.
from numpy import nan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[  9.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   9.,   3.,   2.,   5.],
              [  3.,  nan,   5.,   1.,   3.,  nan,   5.,   1.],
              [  5.,   8.,   2.,   9.,   5.,   8.,   2.,   9.],
              [  9.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   9.,   3.,   2.,   5.],
              [  3.,  nan,   5.,   1.,   3.,  nan,   5.,   1.],
              [  5.,   8.,   2.,   9.,   5.,   8.,   2.,   9.],
              [  9.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   9.,   3.,   2.,   5.],
              [  3.,  nan,   5.,   1.,   3.,  nan,   5.,   1.],
              [  5.,   8.,   2.,   9.,   5.,   8.,   2.,   9.],
              [  9.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   9.,   3.,   2.,   5.],
              [  3.,  nan,   5.,   1.,   3.,  nan,   5.,   1.],
              [  5.,   8.,   2.,   9.,   5.,   8.,   2.,   9.]])

xa = np.arange(8)+2

ya = -np.arange(12)

plt.figure()
plt.contourf(xa,ya,a,100)
plt.show()
```

I'll have:

[image]

I want to interpolate these blanks easier and faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a great interpolation interface where you can just do:

```
import pandas as pd

a_interp = pd.DataFrame(a).interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).values
plt.contourf(xa, ya, a_interp, 100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It solved my problem.. Do you know why this method is far faster than scipy.interpolate.griddata?

Comment: @IurySimões sorry for the late reply, it is because this method does not interpolate a whole new grid, it only interpolates where there are `NaN` values in your already existing grid of values

Comment: Do you know how to use pandas to interpolate to the same grid like griddata? I'm asking because this method u can just interpolate by some axis..

Comment: @IurySimões unfortunately I don't konw, you should elaborate this as a new question... I am sure some fellow will know how to help you